# Spring MVC disallowing fields for specific controller/controller's method

Tags: spring-mvc

I know that I can set allowed fields within the method that is annotated with @InitBinder by calling setAllowedFields on WebDataBinder object. But can I do the same, but only for a specific controller or controller's method? I have a simple form that allows a guest to create a user account and I have another form that allows the login user to update his/her information. In the first form, I want to allow user to insert all the fields(username, password, etc), but in the second form, I want to disallow user to change one of the fields that are allowed in the first form(for example, I want to disallow user to change his/her username). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can do that by just defining in each controller a method annotated with @InitBinder. Each @InitBinder method and the settings you make in this method are dedicated to the method handlers defined in the controller that contains the method annotated with @InitBinder.Thus,in my case,i just could define another method annotated with @InitBinder in another controller and set whatever fields i want to be allowed there.